# A Mime Format Received from WhatsApp Hook. Problem is how to create file by this mime media response in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

```
axios.get(
    ImageURL,
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer {Token}',
        }
    })
    .then( response => {
        
        fs('image.jpeg', {utf8: true}, response.data,(err)=>{

        })
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            r,
            message: 'Successfully Created',
        });
    }).
catch(err => {
console.log(err)
});
```

> I have received data in mime format which looks like this below

```
    JFIF  C  


        
%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(  C   



(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((   @"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While the response is received that's binary data and I want to save it in the directory as an image file because postman is showing the image but how do I convert it to a file and save it to the directory? So how to convert it

Comment: Data Display in console like this 

x A S.O  R!   cg        ) O 'i     U     F9 qE |̀X o ;`   ?ҕ  N    % 
   =1ҤR;  WA %   y/ T i \    Q  "   0?: @ \U+  W ̲e8  <q   
FӬ   [    *ڜ`  S y 9& H   zu  l      J4 "p, q \W * \/? :0IZ  eq    v   ¤m _    / U   fȆB       ϯK  H 4 ? |m?W )WL   O   WL r  zS M    ՅiL  ͅ ?   L4 =  O   S A Rqޮț  J  ci ~W *TҴ 9       X^q  jX    a]  ѴӢ;f     Y    O       l E? j ^  B  *      Y߄ 
 4 3  e ~ *  2-idKl =#L  u   ?§MK Ιc   O Pj g I".  Ѵ  X vO  H#:^     ,M ZN Y 3!MI  V   ?¬